# Why is my secret not being picked up in my github workflo

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, github-pages, github-api

I am trying to incorporate a secret in my project's workflow to set an environment variable and it is just returning an empty string as if the secret were not set at all. My workflow file is as follows:

```
name: Build and Deploy
env:
  CI: false
  REACT_APP_GITHUB_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_GITHUB_API_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_GITHUB_USER: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_GITHUB_USER }}

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'     
        required: true
        default: 'warning'

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: github-pages
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # If you're using actions/checkout@v2 you must set persist-credentials to false in most cases for the deployment to work correctly.

      - name: Install and Build  # This example project is built using npm and outputs the result to the 'build' folder. Replace with the commands required to build your project, or remove this step entirely if your site is pre-built.
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
        env:
          REACT_APP_GITHUB_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_GITHUB_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_GITHUB_USER: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_GITHUB_USER }}

      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
        with:
          ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET_TOKEN }}
          BRANCH: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
          FOLDER: build # The folder the action should deploy.
```

I have set the secrets and both the environment `github-pages` level *and* the repository level trying to get this to work. Tried including them in the build steps of the workflow and the over arching workflow.
[image]

I'm not sure what else to try at this point. For reference this is a React application going onto github pages. https://github.com/ben8622/personal-site

I've tried setting both repository and environment level secrets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the secrets under the inputs in your workflow. Here is what you will need to do:

```
workflow_dispatch:
  inputs:
    logLevel:
      description: 'Log level'     
      required: true
      default: 'warning'
  secrets:
    REACT_APP_GITHUB_API_KEY: 
      required: true
    REACT_APP_GITHUB_USER:
      required: true
```

(and you do not need to define the secrets as env variables)